# Illegal char <:> at index 55: com.example.apk.app-mergeDebugResources-27:/values/values.xml

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-studio, compiler-errors

how can i fix this? I'm not very pratical with android studio and i'm trying to decompile an apk with jadx, putted all the java files and all the assets, when trying to compile it's giving this error
If anyone can help me i'll be grateful

Comment: How to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are two things you need for debugging: a clear description of what you did, and a clear description of how it failed. You've given us the second but not the first.